# Make an automated program open and read from the newest Excel file every day

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I'm creating a program for work that should read data once a day, every day, from a network file path that adds a new spreadsheet daily. It would then write this to a database table. I'm not sure how to customize the xlWorkBook and xlWorkSheet objects to get them to open a different file every time they run. If it helps, the newly added sheets every day will be nearly identical and have the same formatting. Here is what I have so far:

```
    Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
  Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim range As Excel.Range
    Dim rCnt As Integer
    Dim cCnt As Integer
    Dim Obj As Object

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(My.Settings.Bad_Meter_Path)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

    For rCnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count
        For cCnt = 1 To range.Columns.Count
            Obj = xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).ToString
            MsgBox(Obj.value)
        Next
    Next

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Will your app be running 24/7? Or do you plan on having it scheduled to run at certain times each day?
If you want to run it 24/7 you could use the FileSystemWatcher ([example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/150149-using-filesystemwatcher-in-vbnet/)). If not are your files named in a way you can tell the difference between this day's file and the last?

Comment: Well, I have been told I will set it up with Windows Task Scheduler. I will probably set it to run around 2:45 PM each day to be safe, because the new files I want daily seem to always be added around 2:30-2:31. And the files all have the same non-number characters in the names but different numbers following. The number always goes up by a fixed amount

Comment: Have a look at [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can scan all of the files in a directory and check the name and/or creation time of each.

Comment: LMAO, I just checked the files again and realized the numbers follow this format: YYYYMMDDTTTT, with T being time. The time isn't always exact, sometimes it runs at 2:30, sometimes at 2:31, and sometimes both. I wouldn't care I just want whatever is the latest

Comment: Coworker still suggesting I write some code to loop through all the files in the directory and pick the youngest file every time. How would I do that? Is that possible through the "Directory.GetFiles" listed above?

Comment: The youngest file would be `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xlsx").Select(fi => new FileInfo(fi)).OrderByDescending(fi => fi.CreationTimeUtc).First().FullName` but I'm not sure how much of a hit that would be over a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

This below code is in VBA but it will help you get going.

```
Sub myTest()
    strPath As String
    strType As String

    'The full path of the directory (String). For example, "c:\files\excel\"
    strPath = "C:\Users\aa24800\Documents\Vinda\Windows7_Defect_Details"

    'The file specification (String). For example, "*.xls", "*.xlsx" for Excel workbooks.
    strType = ".xls"

    MsgBox "Newest file is: " & NewestFile(strPath, strType)
End Sub

Function NewestFile(Directory, FileSpec)
' Returns the name of the most recent file in a Directory
' That matches the FileSpec (e.g., "*.xlsx", "*.xls").
' Returns an empty string if the directory does not exist or
' it contains no matching files
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MostRecentFile As String
    Dim MostRecentDate As Date
    If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then Directory = Directory & "\"
    FileName = Dir(Directory & "*" & FileSpec, 0)
    If FileName <> "" Then
        MostRecentFile = FileName
        MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
        Do While FileName <> ""
            If FileDateTime(Directory & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
                 MostRecentFile = FileName
                 MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
             End If
             FileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
    NewestFile = MostRecentFile
End Function
```

The you can use this latest file name in your code.